# Linked lists problems

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to teach myself c++ and I am really confused with linked lists. I have been reading through textbooks and looking online but I am really confused how they work. I found an exercise online that I have been trying to figure out, but I am not getting anywhere with it.

Here is the list.h file:

```
struct node 
{
    int val;
    struct node *next;
};

int length(struct node *);
void push(struct node **, int); //add to front of list
void append(struct node **, int); //add to rear of list
void print(struct node *, int);
```

I am having a hard time trying to write the functions for length, push and append.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Theory of linked lists? Creating a `.c` file? Note that the functions you're declaring are plain old C, so maybe this should be tagged a C question?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I dont know how to implement push and append to the linked list. I was hoping I could get some pointers to help me out

Comment: Did you already start implementing these methods on your own? If so, can you add your code, so we can see what's wrong? Also, as @MartinStettner already pointed out: This looks like C, are you sure this is supposed to be C++?

Comment: Linked list algorithms are usually best understood by drawing pictures.

Comment: @Eric - I don't see any semblance with `c++`.  If I were to give you some codes, it will be in `c` and somewhat different than your declarations.

Answer (score 0):

A linked list is simply a string of `Node` classes string together, with each owning a pointer whose address is that of the next `Node` class in the list.

It's pretty simple if you think of it this way:

Coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e71c5e31b58673c

```
#include <iostream>

//Proper encapsulation is not included for terseness and clarity
class Node {
public:
    int num;
    Node* next;

    Node(int n) :
        num(n),
        next(nullptr) {
    };

    ~Node() {}
};

int main() {
    Node a(0);
    Node b(1);
    Node c(2);
    Node d(3);
    Node e(4);

    //String the nodes together, linking like metal chainlinks
    a.next = &b;
    b.next = &c;
    c.next = &d;
    d.next = &e;

    //Can you see how the "link" actually works here?
    //Each Node's "next" pointer points to the next node.
    std::cout << "Node a: " << a.num << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Node b: " << a.next->num << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Node c: " << a.next->next->num << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Node d: " << a.next->next->next->num << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Node e: " << a.next->next->next->next->num << std::endl;

    //What if I were to point e to the start of a?
    e.next = &a;

    std::cout << "Node e->next: " << e.next->num << std::endl;
    //It's node a!

    //Node e.next is now accessible through the linked list:
    std::cout << "Node e->next = a.next->next->next->next->next: " << a.next->next->next->next->next->num << std::endl;

    //Usually people just use a for loop for this type of stuff.
    //Let's use a lambda function to write one right here:
    auto index_func = [](Node* head, size_t index) {
        Node* current = head;
        Node* next = head->next;

        for (int i = 0; i < index; ++i) {
            if (next != nullptr) {
                //Hey, look at the pointers fly!
                current = next;
                next = current->next;
            } else {
                std::cout << "Whoops, we hit a null pointer before we got to our index!" << std::endl;
                break;
            }
        }

        return current->num;
    };

    //This is the same as finding the 6th node in the list (but since it's zero-indexing it's [5])
    std::cout << index_func(&a, 5) << std::endl;

    //We can also continue to do this:
    std::cout << index_func(&a, 499) << std::endl;
    //This is me accessing the 500th element, which, since our back links to our head node, it's the 4th node, d.

    return 0;   
}
```

You can probably imagine the other shenanigans we can do with linked lists if we decide to insert a `Node` between `a` or `e` simply be reassigning pointers.

Answer (score 0):

```
void push(struct node **list, int newVal) { //add to front of list
  struct node* firstNode = *list;
  struct node* newNode = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  if (newNode == NULL) abort();
  newNode->val = newVal;
  newNode->next = firstNode;
  *list = newNode;
}

void append(struct node **list, int newVal){ //add to rear of list
  if (*list == NULL) {
    push(list, newVal);
    return;
  }

  /* Locate last node in list*/
  struct node* curNode = *list;
  while (curNode->next != NULL) 
    curNode = curNode->next;

  /* Add a new node at the end of the list */
  struct node* newNode = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  if (newNode == NULL) abort();
  newNode->val = newVal;
  newNode->next = NULL;
  curNode->next = newNode;
}
```

Comment: It will break on append if the list is empty because `curNode` will be `NULL` and therefore you can't evaluate `curNode->next`.